# Good overview on mixin in ruby

Tags: ruby, mixins

I am a .NET developer and I want to learn more about how mixins are used in other languages. As mixins are well established in Ruby, I want to ask about good ressources on how mixins can be used in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

- [A brief intro](http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/a/mixin.htm)
- [Mixin Tutorial](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/)
- [Chapter from 'Programming Ruby'](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html)
- [The RubyLearning notes on Mixins](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/modules_mixins.html)

Answer (score 0):

[The Ruby Programming Language](http://books.google.com/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA250&lpg=PA250&dq=the%20ruby%20programming%20language%20mixins&source=bl&ots=fIAgAg4rbB&sig=XSprCJZUk3XKNwLVhvFA2PAvvXE&hl=en&ei=JkKLTdb8DsnegQegibnZDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) has a short and sweet description of mixins. I believe it is mentioned more throughout the book, but the linked section will give you the general overview.